# Python3 Multiprocessing not all iterable is processed all the time when using zip function

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have a simple function

```
@click.command()
@click.option('--concurrency', default=multiprocessing.cpu_count(), help='The maximum requests to make to the server')
@click.option('--file', prompt='File Location: ', type=click.File(encoding="utf8"),
              help='The File to load')
    def try_pool(file, concurrency):
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(concurrency)
        pool.map(print, zip(file, [1]*3000) )
        pool.close()

    def simple_print(file)
        for i in zip(file, [1]*3000):
            print(i)


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        load_service()
```

the file contains only 2879 entries. 
if I use the simple_print function I get the following (with many tries)

```
python3 Test.py input.txt | wc -l
    2879
```

However, if I uses try_pool multiple times, sometimes I will get 2879, sometimes I get 2519, sometimes 2430.

I am wondering what is going on with multiprocessing module. The version of python I am using is Python 3.4.3

Comment: How are you calling `try_pool`?

Comment: not sure why it matters how I call try_pool. It is wrapped by a click option.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the answer.

Apparently calling pool.close() is not enough to make the pool handle all the requests.  It must be followed by pool.join() to wait for the pool to complete.

```
def try_pool(file, concurrency):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(concurrency)
    pool.map(print, zip(file, [1]*3000) )
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Now I really wish those two methods are combined into one so it won't cause stupid mistakes like I did.